# Webmatrix crashing whenever site is opened or created

Tags: webmatrix

A couple of days ago I tried to open my Orchards MVC site from WebMatrix and it crashed. Currently any site I try and open, or even if I attempt to create an empty site, causes WebMatrix to stop working. I get windows error dialog box telling me that "Web Matrix Has Stopped Working". I am completely at a loss on what caused this. I already posted on the iis.net forums (http://forums.iis.net/post/2061458.aspx) but have not received a reply.

I have restarted, uninstalled and resinstalled both WebMatrix and IIS 8 express.

There are two errors in the event viewer. Detailed below. Anyhow would be very appreciated since this is keeping me from working on my site.

Thanks in advance.

First Error

```
Application: WebMatrix.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager.GetMatchedContent(Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpProviderLevelContent, Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.IApplicationStateChangedContext)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager+HelpContent.<GetContent>b__22(Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpProviderLevelContent)
at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Lookup`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Create[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>>, System.Func`2<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>,System.__Canon>, System.Func`2<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>,System.__Canon>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<System.__Canon>)
at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager+HelpContent.GetContent(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.IDynamicHelpContentProvider>)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager+<GetHelpHistoryEnumerator>d__1b.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`2<System.__Canon,Boolean>)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager.get_LatestHelp()
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager.RaiseLatestHelpContentUpdated()
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpManager.OnApplicationStateChanged(System.Object, Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.ApplicationStateChangedEventArgs)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.DynamicHelp.ApplicationStateWhenInputIdleNotifier.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.SingletonBackgroundAction+<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0(System.Object)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.SingletonBackgroundAction`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].RunAction(System.__Canon)
at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.SingletonBackgroundAction`1+<>c__DisplayClass3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<Schedule>b__1(System.Object)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Second Error

```
Faulting application name: WebMatrix.exe, version: 7.1.1932.0, time stamp: 0x52589c06
Faulting module name: Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.ni.dll, version: 7.1.1932.0, time stamp: 0x52589c13
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x005e9398
Faulting process id: 0x2318
Faulting application start time: 0x01cedff7bbec8f10
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\WebMatrix.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.W38826ba1#\89265eccf2f3657048b6111d09c73386\Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.ni.dll
Report Id: fd0ed1bd-4bea-11e3-bec0-98fc11e3977e
Faulting package full name:
```

Comment: I have same problem. is there any solution?

Comment: So far nothing. I have not been able to figure out why it happened or how to fix it. I have moved on to using IIS directly and deploying from a laptop for the few sites I have to have web matrix for. Wish I could be more help. I am hoping the next major update will fix it.

Comment: Remove Webmatrix3 and install Webmatrix2, this is solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall Webmatrix3 and install Webmatrix2, this is solved my problem

Comment: Where did you get Webmatrix2? Every install link I have found is dead. Do you have a working one?

Comment: Try this and check my answer as accepted: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/7/8573745C-384B-4F74-BE2C-D85C390742D5/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi

Comment: That did it thanks. If anyone ever figures out how to get Matrix 3 working let us know.

Comment: Almost a year later, this is still not working in 3... This is still the workaround, AFAIK.

Comment: WNewquay below has a much easier answer.

Answer (score 26):

I did NOT have to uninstall WebMatrix 3. I just deleted this folder and its contents.

C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebMatrix

Comment: Worked for me the same way

Comment: God knows why this isn't marked as the right answer it's better than uninstalling and re-installing. 

For some people it may also be worthwhile deleting the applicationhost.config file but it doesn't work for everyone.

Comment: Please make this the answer, very helpful! tnx

Comment: Deleted only the Folders that included the Word Cache and it worked

Comment: It did not work out. I reinstall webmatrix 3 and it got okk.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I guess the issue is caused by a php component installed. Anyway, the following steps solve my issue.

```
1) Remove Webmatrix 3
2) Delete C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebMatrix
3) Reinstall Webmatrix 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To solve it:

1. Uninstall Web Matrix
2. Backup My Web Sites directory
3. search for WebMatrix on the C:\ and delete everything including DLL
4. Re-install WebMatrix

Answer (score 0):

Even if I try and open my site with webmatrix3, to create an empty site causes WebMatrix to stop working.

Solution for me

1.) Remove Webmatrix 3 
2.) Delete C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebMatrix 
3.) Reinstall Webmatrix 3

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to uninstall webmatrix. Just deleting the folder as above worked.

Delete C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebMatrix

Unbelievable though that it's still an issue? How many years later..?

Comment: This answer does not add much to [the most voted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26558358/4453460): you could add a *comment* to that one, stating that the issue can still happen nowadays (which would be an useful comment).

Answer (score 0):

uninstalled Webmatrix 3

Delete C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebMatrix

installed webmatrix 2 works for my sites